# Windows 7 Move folder without confirmation(force overwrite)

Tags: windows-7, file-management

Using Windows 7 - if you move one folder to a different folder it will ask you to confirm replacing that folder, and you get a confirmation dialog for the files as well.

Is there shortcuts to forcing overwrites, without any confirmation dialogs at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of replacing the copy/move handler with an alternative, I don't think it's possible by default in Windows 7.

Check out [**TeraCopy**](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php), it's one of the free copy/move handlers. It replaces the copy and move functions with its own optimized functions. It works with Windows 7, even in 64-bits.

Even with TeraCopy, you'll get a confirmation dialog for overwriting files. But you will get 1 and only 1 notification if you select (Overwrite) "All".

[image]

In my humble opinion, it's pretty dangerous to always overwrite files without asking for a confirmation. A human error arrives so quickly ... nobody can avoid copying/moving the wrong stuff at the wrong place ...

Comment: The problem comes from, Drag folder holding shift "Confirm move folder names exist?" 'check do all current' YES  "Oh noes there's files it will replace!" 'check do next 334 conflicts' YES. Need to click 4 different things is just fail.